# How to remove CSS style?

Tags: css

I have a block with div inside:

```
<div>
   <div class="do">Do it</div>
</div>
```

Element `.do` has `cursor: none`, but parent div has cursor.

How to remove cursor from `.do` element? Now parent block sets this property

Comment: Can you provide an example of it not working as intended?

Comment: Tread carefully. Hiding the cursor is bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should come with simple rule

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.do {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div class="do">Do it</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably dealing with CSS Precedence Rule. Have a look at this [Specificity doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for further details.

I am assuming, this is what's happening (Pasted code from Nicolae's answer)

```css
.withCursor > .withoutCursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.withCursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.withoutCursor {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="withCursor">
   <div class="withoutCursor">Do it</div>
</div>
```

As you may notice, the rule for `.withoutCursor` gets overridden by the `.withCursor > .withoutCursor`.

If you figure out the right selector for your `.do`, or remove the one that overrides it, this should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.withCursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.withoutCursor {
  cursor: none;
}

.withInitialCursor {
  cursor: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="withCursor">
   <div class="withoutCursor">None</div>
   <div class="withInitialCursor">Cursor initial</div>
   <div>Cursor pointer - inherited</div>
</div>
```

You can just do `cursor: none` to the inner element.